# "Диктат западной культуры" негласное правило ru.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: обсуждение

С толкнулся с таким вопросом [Как изменить язык в Android Stuido?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/665032/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%B2-android-stuido) посмотрев его , а также посмотрев ответ. Посчитал его не во всём корректным ,  дал свой ответ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошло немного времени и его просто удалили.

После начала разбирательства я понял, что я нарушил не гласное правило:

> Думать, а также производить, развивать и создавать ПО надо только на Американском языке.

После этого я задумался вопросом. А чем тогда этот сайт отличается от таких сетевых ресурсов как [Цензор.NET](http://censor.net.ua)  и [БиБиСи](https://www.bbc.com/russian) ?

И является ли этот сайт нейтральным по отношению к той культуре, частью которой я являюсь?

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы **не** являетесь нейтральным по отношению к каким бы то ни было культурам и вместо ответа по существу скатываетесь в субъективное обсуждение этой самой культуры.

Comment: (Но упоминание латыни из принятого ответа я бы, пожалуй, всё-таки убрал, ибо это тоже не по существу. И видимо не я один, судя по истории правок)

Answer (score 14):

> Которое гласит так : думать, а также производить, развивать и создавать ПО надо только на Американском языке.

Такого никто не утверждал.

Заголовок вашего вопроса никак не связан с проблемой ответа.

Ответ был исправлен, т.к:

1. Там была куча информации, которая не относится к вопросу вообще.
2. Попытка розжига на национальной почве.

> И является ли этот сайт нейтральным по отношению к той культуре, частью которой я являюсь ??

Этот сайт для вопросов о разработке/администрировании и т.д. Поэтому, просим, ещё раз, воздержаться от подобных политически высказываний, которые никак не связаны с вопросами как таковыми.

Comment: тут нет политики просто понятный **факт либо развиваешь свою культуру либо чужую** и мой ответ удалили по тому что он ставил верный ответ что нужно развивать **свою** культуру . Именно по этому его удалили , такбы ну насобирал бы он пяток другой минусов и все бы о нём забыли . НО нет нужен **строгий диктат** . **Зачем нужен диктат ??** дайте вразумительный ответ. И пожалуйста не уходите в демагогию

Comment: @timob256 ответ должен быть по существу, а вы мало того что ответ толком не дали, так еще и в него всякого лишнего понаписали.

Answer (score 8):

> думать, а также производить, развивать и создавать ПО надо только на Американском языке.

- Во первых нет такого языка Американский — есть Американский Английский.
- Думать вас никто не может заставить на каком-то языке, это же ваши мысли ;)
- Не зря у нас Stack Overflow на русском, => "негласного правилa" не то что нет, но даже наоборот. (кстати, если вы так цените русский язык, то хоть орфографию соблюдайте "негласный", а не "не гласный")
- А в вашем ответе, просто была написана какая-то несуразица, которую вырезали, а вы откатили  — модераторы предупреждали, что не надо.

Кстати, вот мое мнение: "производить, развивать и создавать ПО" действительно лучше по-английски, смотря конечно, что за цель...